# Xcode 8 - unexpectedly found nil

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I just started learning swift and i have a question.
I have two view controllers, and i'm trying to send a string from view 1 to view 2.

This is what i've got so far:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
{
if segue.identifier =="1"
{
let DestViewControl = segue.destination as! ViewController2
DestViewController.count = 9
}
}
```

Count is a variable in view 2. So far this works great.
However, if i want to automatically change the text in a label in view 2, as DestViewController.lb_ExLabem.text = "test" , i get a fatal error "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value".

Let me know if you have any ideas.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the segue, you outlet is nil (since the view is not loaded).

In DestViewController, you should create a variable to store the text:

```
class ViewController2{
    @IBOutlet weak var your_label: UILabel!
    var label_tex=String()
}
```

Initiate it in prepareForSegue:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
    if segue.identifier =="1"{
        let DestViewControl=segue.destination as! ViewController2
        DestViewController.label_tex="9"
    }
}
```

And finally in ViewController2, change your label text when the view is loaded (and your outlet not nil anymore):

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool){
    your_label.text=label_tex
}
```

Comment: Thanks, thought of this bypass and did it in viewDidLoad, i was just trying to find a way without assigning the label.

Answer (score 1):

`lb_ExLabem` is in your  `DestViewController` and when you are trying to set it like this

```
 DestViewController.lb_ExLabem.text = "test"
```

the value is `nil`.(As the view is lot loaded)

try to set the value of `lb_ExLabem` in `viewWillAppear()` of  `DestViewController` it will work

Answer (score 0):

The error simply means that the value of your `DestViewController.lb_ExLabem` variable is `nil`. Make sure that the variable has a value in it so you don't get an error.